# Proving that second derivative is perpendicular to curve

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, curves, parametrization

How can I prove the following?

$\gamma (t)$ is unit speed, $\dot \gamma(t) \not= 0 \Rightarrow \ddot \gamma(t)$ is perpendicular to $\gamma(t)$

I don't really see where a problem would arise when $\dot \gamma(t)=0$ would cause such a problem

Comment: You're correct. If $\gamma$ has unit speed, that means in particular that $\|\dot\gamma(t)\|=1$ for all $t$. But don't you have a typo in your question? You should be showing that $\ddot\gamma(t)$ is perpendicular to $\dot\gamma(t)$ for all $t$.

Comment: Perhaps I'd better quote the question: Prove that if $\gamma (t)$ is a unit speed curve, then $\ddot \gamma (t)$ is perpendicular to the tangent vector $\dot \gamma (t)$ if it is non-zero

Comment: Is it perhaps just an oddly worded question wishing me to clarify that the speed of a curve can never be zero and thus it is always perpendicular to the normal vector?

Comment: The problem as stated is incorrect. If you know $\|\gamma(t)\|$ is constant *and* the curve has unit speed, then the conclusion is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ted Shifrin allready pointed out you probably want to prove that if $\gamma(t)$ has unit speed then $\gamma'(t)\perp \gamma''(t)$. The proof is completely similar to what you do when you prove that a tangent vector at the sphere is perpenticular to  the point at which it is attached.

Proof: Notice that $\gamma(t)$  has unit speed means $\Vert \gamma'(t) \Vert=1 \Rightarrow  \Vert \gamma'(t) \Vert^2=1$. From this you get:

\begin{eqnarray}
0&=& \frac{d}{dt} 1\\
&=&\frac{d}{dt}\Vert \gamma'(t) \Vert^2\\
&=&\frac{d}{dt}\langle\gamma'(t),\gamma'(t) \rangle\\
&=& \langle\gamma''(t),\gamma'(t) \rangle+\langle\gamma'(t),\gamma''(t) \rangle\\
&=&2 \langle\gamma''(t),\gamma'(t) \rangle 
\end{eqnarray}

And therefore $\langle\gamma''(t),\gamma'(t) \rangle=0$.

Edit: Just to clarify, what Ted means is that the condition that $\gamma$ has unit speed allready implies that $\gamma'\neq 0$. So the condition that $\gamma'\neq 0$ is superfluous.

Edit 2: Since the question came up in the comments, yes I proved what I think is the correct statement. The statement as you claim it is wrong in general. Take $\gamma(t)=(\sin(t),\cos(t))$. Then $\gamma'(t)=(\cos(t),-\sin(t))$ and $\gamma''(t)=(-\sin(t),-\cos(t))=-\gamma(t)$ and therefore $\gamma''(t)$ is not perpendicular to $\gamma(t)$.

Comment: Does this not show its perpendicular to $\dot \gamma(t)$ instead of $\gamma(t)$?

Comment: @user142702: That's exactly what I told you in the first place was correct. Read my additional comments to see what hypotheses you need to prove the conclusion you stated.

Comment: @user142702 Yes, thats what I wrote. The statement as you claim it is wrong in general. Take $\gamma(t)=(\sin(t),\cos(t))$. Then $\gamma'(t)=(\cos(t),-\sin(t))$ and $\gamma''(t)=(-\sin(t),-\cos(t))=-\gamma(t)$ and therefore $\gamma''(t)$ is not perpendicular to $\gamma(t)$.

Comment: I included the last comment in the answer.

Comment: Yes sorry I didn't realise the typo I managed to make, thank you!

Comment: Sorry for the confusion

Comment: sorry, is there any chance anyone could explain how this step is done? getting from  $\frac{d}{dt}\Vert \gamma'(t) \Vert^2$ to $\frac{d}{dt}\langle\gamma'(t),\gamma'(t) \rangle\\$

Comment: @JoaquinBrandan That’s basically the definition of the (Euclidean) norm.

Comment: Sorry if this is too basic or maybe it's some kind of notation misconception, but isnt $\Vert \gamma'(t) \Vert^2=\sqrt{x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2}^2=x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2$

Comment: @JoaquinBrandan Exactly, and that’s the same as the scalar product. :)

Comment: but if the scalar product gives you a scalar, how do you get a vector $\langle\gamma'(t),\gamma'(t) \rangle\\$ in that step? Sorry i must be missing something, maybe this notation is something im not familiar with.

Comment: wait, is $\langle\gamma'(t),\gamma'(t) \rangle\\$ a different notation for $\gamma'(t)\bullet\gamma'(t) $ ?

Comment: @JoaquinBrandan I‘m not sure where you are stuck. $\langle\gamma‘(t),\gamma‘(t)\rangle$ is not a vector. If you look up the definition of the scalar aka. dot product you get that this is exactly $x‘(t)^2+y‘(t)^2$ which is the same as the norm squared.

Comment: @JoaquinBrandan Just saw your new comment. Yes it is!

Comment: That clears it up then. Thank you so much for your patience. Now everything makes perfect sense.

Comment: Sorry, just one more thing, this proof would seem to work for any other constant speed different to 1, since $\Vert \gamma'(t) \Vert=2 \Rightarrow  \Vert \gamma'(t) \Vert^2=2^2$ and then its also true that $0= \frac{d}{dt} 4\\$, is that right?  (I have searched a lot but I cant find this clarification anywhere)

Comment: @JoaquinBrandan That’s completely right.